# Google login Codeigniter API Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Google_Service_Exception
>
> Message: Error calling GET
> https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me: (403) Legacy People API
> has not been used in project 369152237433 before or it is disabled.
> Enable it by visiting
> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=369152237433
> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
> the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

Why does this issue occur? Can you please help me guys to solve this? I already enabled Google+API and People API.

Error: https://prnt.sc/135mzcp

Comment: You can check google official document for that